# after run xCode lost connection to iPhone - how fix it?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, connection

I have this devices:
-macOS - monterey 12.4
-iPhone 7 - 15.5
-xCode 13.3.1

My user case:

1. I connect the iPhone to Mac, at finder I see my phone.
2. I running XCode, connection is lost, at finder I don't see my phone.
3. Now I can't connect my phone. Finder no longer sees it. just need to restart my phone.

This happened after updating the phone(15.4->15.5), I also updated mac(to 12.4) and xCode(13.3.1 -> 13.4).

what I tried:

1. factory reset my phone
2. reinstall xCode, remove 13.4, install 13.3.1

I can't roll back my iPhone to the old version because Apple no longer signs the old version firmware(15.4.1).

I have already spent a lot of time, but the problem persisted. Any advice - I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the cable to my phone. The old cable worked with Finder but didn't work for XCode.